# php exec is not working in centos

Tags: php, yii, centos, exec

I am trying to use the exec command in centos:

```
exec(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application').'\yiic SendNow '.$sendID);
```

this does not work in centos but this work in windows

Comment: have you tried system() command..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows paths use a backslash separator; unix paths use a forward slash.

Comment: You can use forward slash for both system or use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant.

Comment: @user2431202, any error message? @Vitaly Actually `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is provided for path parsing purposes, it is completely unnessesary to use it to read or exec a file, so just always use `/`